# Standard or idiomatic empty object in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

I often need to define an empty object in C++, which is typically a structure without any members or methods:

```cpp
struct Dummy {};
```

Reincarnations of the same idea include classes like `nill_t`, `null_t`, `Empty`, `None` etc.

I was wondering if there is a **standard library object that fits this description** (empty class, used as tag for "nothing" or "empty") **or a canonical way to define it** (proper name etc). One idea would be to use `std::false_type` but unfortunately this class is far from empty.

---

**Edit**:

Ideally I'd use the Standard None type as a (n empty) base to have both the rich name description and hide implementation (or use it as is, where it makes sense)

```
struct Dummy : std::none {};
struct Noop  : std::none {};
```

Having the language take care of intricasies of "nothingness" like the one @Barry mentions in his answer, or e.g. providing an equality operator that always returns `false` (like NaN) or whatever the language considers "proper behavior" for "nothing" would be nice.

The question merely asks whether there's a standard None or Empty or Nothing type, I never suggested obfuscating the code by using it where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: There's nothing bad in defining your own, and afaik the standard doesn't give you anything for that. If you wanted there's `std::monostate` which matches the description; though its intended usage is relatively narrow.

Comment: How do you use this empty class?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili as a signifier for nothing, as the default tag in struct templates, as the default tag in function templates, as the "no output" tag in a processing pipeline, as the equivalent of Python's `None` in some generic code. Every use case has a couple variations, but generally that's it. The codebase I'm working on has 12 variations of "empty" without special meaning attached to them, i.e. they could all use a single "empty" tag instead of saying "empty", "nothing", "none", "dummy", "dummyObject" and so on. Hope this helps

Comment: @LorahAttkins: "*as the default tag in struct templates, as the default tag in function templates, as the "no output" tag in a processing pipeline, as the equivalent of Python's None in some generic code*" All of these are different use cases, so the answer would be different in each case. I don't know what a "default tag" is, but I would probably call that `default`. Discarding a value in a pipeline would be `discard` or `drop`. Etc. None of the names you suggested fit those particular situations. Make the code readable and be expressive.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ideally I'd use the Standard `None` type as a (n empty) base to have both the rich name description and hide implementation. The question merely asks whether there's a standard `None` or `Empty` or `Nothing` type, I never suggested obfuscating the code by using it where it doesn't make sense. As for the comment you quote I was asked for some uses, I provided some uses.

Comment: @LorahAttkins: "*Ideally I'd use the Standard None type as a (n empty) base to have both the rich name description and hide implementation.*" ... implementation? It's *empty*; what implementation is there to hide? A type being empty is self-documenting because... there's nothing in it. If `false_type` is not considered "empty" (even though `std::is_empty_v` would disagree), then I would say that a base class would *also* not be considered "empty". So you shouldn't be able to inherit from this "None" type anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas Empty as in "a non-union class type with no non-static data members other than bit-fields of size 0, no virtual functions, no virtual base classes, and no non-empty base classes". So implementation wise, are we going to provide an explicit constructor, will the type be comparable, assignable or immutable, should it be hashable, convertible to other types etc. Other "behavioral" aspects pertain to what member function we should `=delete` since an empty implementation generates stuff that we might want to ban). IMHO there is implementation to design.

Comment: @LorahAttkins: My point is that you declared that `std::false_type` is "far from empty", yet it fulfills the criteria `is_empty` outlines. So either you have your own private definition of "empty" (and you should edit your question to explain what it is) or your statement that `false_type` doesn't count is wrong (and you should remove the statement that it doesn't count).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice is to do it this way:

```cpp
struct Dummy { explicit Dummy() = default; };
```

Which you can then create an instance of:

```cpp
inline constexpr Dummy dummy;
```

The advantage of this is that `Dummy` is not an aggregate (in C++20), which prevents this from compiling:

```cpp
void f(Dummy);

f({});      // error
f(Dummy{}); // ok
f(dummy);   // ok
```

Which is important because the point of tag types is visibility, and `{}` is... not that.

---

> I was wondering if there is a standard library object that fits this description

There are quite a few standard library empty tag types (e.g. `std::nullopt_t`), but if you need a tag type, you need it for a particular reason and reusing an existing tag just to avoid creating a new type doesn't seem like a good tradeoff. I mean, use `std::nullopt_t` if that makes sense for what you're doing (perhaps you're doing something equivalent to `optional` and so that's a reasonable tag to use for this problem) but don't just use `std::nullopt_t` because... you need a tag and that's available.

Comment: I can see the value in the explicit constructor, nice. At the end, all I need is a single type to replace multiple types that all mean "`nothing`"(ness). I can see the difference between `monostate` and `nullopt` but I wouldn't be doing tag dispatching based on variatians of "nothing" anyways.

Answer (score 11):

The C++ standard library actually has a large number of "empty" types. `std::monostate`, `std::nullopt_t`, the `std::in_place_t` tag types, etc. They all have different names because they are used for different purposes.

You should not have one all-purpose "empty" type, because seeing the name there will tell you what the code is doing. `std::optional<T>(std::in_place, ...)` communicates a lot more about what is going on than `std::optional<T>(std::monostate{}, ...)`.

Indeed, if a single type were used, you wouldn't be able to differentiate between `std::optional<T>(std::nullopt)` and `std::optional<T>(std::in_place)`. These are two very different function calls.

The name you use should be whatever makes the code which uses it readable.

As for canonical conventions, the C++ standard uses certain conventions based on how you're using it. Types that the user is expected to type directly into their code, like `std::monostate`, are named normally. You're expected to create `variant`s that use `monostate` in the type.

Tag types, used to select constructor or `operator()` overloads, will typically end in `_t`. But they also have an `inline constexpr` variable defined for them that doesn't end in `_t`. For example, `std::nullopt_t` is the name of the type, while `std::nullopt` is the name of a variable of that type.

This is particularly important, as `std::nullopt_t`'s cannot directly be constructed by the user. You can copy `std::nullopt` instances around, but you cannot create a `std::nullopt_t` instance directly.

That last bit is something the standard is a bit inconsistent about. Most tag types don't have this requirement; you can invoke `std::in_place_t{}` all you like. But `std::nullopt_t` does.

---

Examples from your comment:

> as the default tag in struct templates, as the default tag in function templates

I don't know what a "default tag" is in this context, but I would probably call it `default_t`. Since that spells out the meaning of the thing.

> as the "no output" tag in a processing pipeline

I would spell this `void` or if that's not an option, `drop` or `discard`.

> as the equivalent of Python's None in some generic code

That already has a name: `nullptr`. If it is a non-pointer that may or may not be present, it's spelled `std::optional<T>`. And if you really are in generic code, `std::nullopt` itself works as a way to indicate that the user conceptually provided an empty `optional`.

These are different uses with different interpreted meaning. Therefore, they should not have the same name even if they're all *implemented* as equivalent types.

Comment: `nullptr_t` is another one. It's just difficult to recommend something without knowing how OP is planning to use it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `nullptr_t` is certainly not another one, espeacially because its size is `sizeof(void *)`

Comment: @LorahAttkins how is sizeof related? Are you planning to have a container full of `nullptr`s?

Comment: @LorahAttkins: `sizeof(empty_type)` could *also* be `sizeof(void*)`. There's nothing in C++ to prevent that (though you're unlikely to encounter it in the wild). However, `std::is_empty_v<std::nullptr_t>` will return "false", so your point is still valid.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili as Nicol says, `std::is_empty_v<T>` is the litmus test. `nullptr_t` is far from being an "empty" type. When a type has `sizeof > 1` it is a good indicator of not being an empty type. Obviously in C++ you can't have sizeof==0, so 1 is a viable size for a type that would match the implementation I show in the question

Comment: @LorahAttkins you didn't mention `std::is_empty` as a requirement in the question (or relevance of size). How is that relevant for the use cases you mentioned in the comments? Do you check for `std::is_empty` for metaprogramming or what? Your question definitely needs clarity

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Woudn't it be peculiar to have `sizeof(Empty)`=8? or `sizeof(Nothing)`=8? In any case I do mention an implementation with no members or bases (`struct Dummy`) which is what all the "nothing" structures do.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Also I mention the requirement for "empty" since the first version of the question "One idea would be to use std::false_type but unfortunately this class is far from empty."

Comment: I don't think the size has any relevance. Why is `std::false_type` "far from empty"? `static_assert(std::is_empty_v<std::false_type>);` test passes and its size is (usually?) 1. Again, your question needs clarification.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 introduced [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate). It is meant to be used with `std::variant` but also fits nicely "empty class, used as tag for "nothing" or "empty"".

It comes with a couple of related free functions that enable most common comparisons, but otherwise is nothing more than:

```
struct monostate { };
```